# How to show all files with some filters?

Tags: files, ls

I need to display on screen all the files that hang recursively from the root and that have not been modified in the last two days, with a size smaller than 5 KB.

I can show the files that hang recursively from the root with ls -R but it also show me directories, i dont know if is there any way to show only the files with the filters that i write.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: What do you mean by "files that hang recursively from the root"?

Comment: @Sato, files hang from the directory tree, like apples hang from the apple tree.

Comment: All the files that are inside all the folders that hang from the root, and if that folder has another folder inside with more files, that also shows those files. That's what ls -R does.

Comment: There are many related Qs and even duplicates e.g. [Files greater than 1 GB and older than 6 months](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/203129) or [Find files that match a certain size and modification time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/258737)

Comment: Ok, nice! Im going to try with this and the answer of Stephen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should able to do that with `find` and something like:

```
find / -mtime +1 -type f
```

1. find starting from root: `/`
2. select anything that has not been modified in the last two days (48 hours): `-mtime +1`
3. only select files: `-type f`

**Be careful with units on mtime**

As mentioned in comments and explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92346/why-does-find-mtime-1-only-return-files-older-than-2-days), be aware of what the units on `-mtime +1` means and then match that to your expectations.

Comment: Yeah! That is. I add -size 5k to limit the size to 5 Kb and done. Thank you!

Comment: You fell into the trap. `-mtime +2` is for the files whose age rounded down to an integer number of days is strictly greater than 2. So that's for files that are exactly 3 days old or older.

Comment: @TheRedosan, `-size 5k` (in find implementations that support the `k` suffix) is for files whose size is inbetween 4097 (4KiB+1byte) and 5120 (5KiB). Use `-size -5000c` for files smaller than 5KB (between 0 and  4999 bytes).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, thanks for the clarification. I added a note of explanation.

Comment: IOW, `-mtime +2` is for the files that have not been modified in the last **3** days.